# `Double.ToString` with N number of decimal places

Tags: c#

I know that if we want to display a `double` as a two decimal digit, one would just have to use

```
public void DisplayTwoDecimal(double dbValue)
{
  Console.WriteLine(dbValue.ToString("0.00"));
}
```

But how to extend this to `N` decimal places, where `N` is determined by the user?

```
 public void DisplayNDecimal(double dbValue, int nDecimal)
    {
     // how to display
    }
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use "Nx" for x decimal digits.

```
 public void DisplayNDecimal(double dbValue, int nDecimal)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(dbValue.ToString("N" + nDecimal));
 }
```

Comment: side effect of using Nx is that the number will be formatted with thousands separators, i.e "1,234.5600"

Comment: If you don't want thousands separators, you can use `Fx`

Comment: This should have a link to docs on the different formatting prefixes. Also, +1 for a great hint (that I discovered **after** writing my own extension method doing precisely that).

Answer (score -3):

I would use this:

```
public string DisplayNDecimal(double dbValue, int nDecimal)
{
    string decimalPoints = "0";
    if (nDecimal > 0)
    {
        decimalPoints += ".";
        for (int i = 0; i < nDecimal; i++)
            decimalPoints += "0";
    }
    return dbValue.ToString(decimalPoints);
}
```

:)

Here is it with `StringBuilder` (though probably not more efficient and definitely would require more resources)

```
public string DisplayNDecimal(double dbValue, int nDecimal)
{
    StringBuilder decimalPoints = new StringBuilder("0");
    if (nDecimal > 0)
    {
        decimalPoints.Append(".");
        for (int i = 0; i < nDecimal; i++)
            decimalPoints.Append("0");
    }
    return dbValue.ToString(decimalPoints.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why not use built in formatters??

Comment: Keep in mind this won't work for all cultures as all cultures don't use a period for a decimal point.