# c# convert double to string keeping trailing 0s

Tags: c#, .net

I need to develop a function in c# to validate some customized formats (not the native ones).
In order to do that I need to analyse char by char of the value that I am getting to find out if it is in the correct format.

The values that I will get could be something like:

```
1.00020
4.00155001
6.000000
5.10000000000
0.00000000000000
```

However I am struggling to convert those numbers to string keeping the same shape.
**I can't really use the formats provided by the framework because I don't know how many decimals places the value that I will get has.**

To get around of this I tried to use `(BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits((decimal)valueCheck)[3])[2])` 
to find out the number of decimal places and then use `.ToString("Format")`, **however it does not consider 0's at the end.**

The question is simple: **How can I convert a double to string in order to always keep exactly the same number and decimal places when I don't know how many decimal places my input has?**

Comment: Why don't you get them as string at first?

Comment: Some helpful references for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/764102/6741868, [Decimal.GetBits Method (Decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx), http://stackoverflow.com/a/3059792/6741868.

Comment: @mok If I convert it to string at first, I will not keep trailing 0s.