# Add decimal places to a decimal value

Tags: c#, decimal

I have an api that receive a decimal value as string.

e.g: `"1.96"`

I am parsing this string value with this code:

```
decimal.TryParse("1,96", out myDecimalVar)
```

But I need the following decimal value: `1.96000`

How can I do it without `Math.Round`? Because `Math.Round` returns `1.97000`

Tks!

Comment: That *is* the decimal value you have, are you trying to display this as a string somewhere?

Comment: what do you need? decimal or string?

Comment: If you want just an string format with N decimals, take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059759/double-tostring-with-n-number-of-decimal-places

Comment: There is no way that Math.Round turns `1.96000` into `1.97000`.  Your input is not what you think it is.

Comment: Hi, I need a decimal, not string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `double` and `float`, `decimal` is a `BCD` (*Binary Decimal*),
so you can *play a trick*:

```
 // Be sure, that your current culture uses "," (comma)
 // as a decimal separator (e.g. Russian, ru-Ru culture)
 decimal.TryParse("1,96", out myDecimalVar);

 // add up a special form of zero
 myDecimalVar += 0.00000m;

 // 1,96000
 Console.Write(myDecimalVar);
```

for details, please, see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx

> The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign,
> a 96-bit **integer number**, and a **scaling factor** used to divide the
> 96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction.
> The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent
> ranging from 0 to 28.

So we have `myDecimalVar` being turned into `196000` **integer number** with `-5` **scale factor**.

A more *natural way*, however, is to *parse* as it is, and *represent* as you want with a help of formatting:

```
 decimal.TryParse("1,96", out myDecimalVar);
 ...
 Console.Write(myDecimalVar.ToString("F5")); // 5 digits after the decimal point
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it as a string then:

```
`       string v = "1.96";
        decimal d;
        decimal.TryParse(v, out d);
        Console.Write(d.ToString("f4"));
`
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need a decimal output. thnks

Answer (score 0):

You have vary alternatives

```
decimal myDecimalVar;
decimal.TryParse("1,96", out myDecimalVar);
Console.WriteLine(myDecimalVar.ToString("0.00000")); // 1,96000
Console.WriteLine(myDecimalVar.ToString("F5"));      // 1,96000
```

as already answered.

Comment: Yeah, but I need a decimal output. thnks